Template friend function of two typenames for a template class
I try to make a template function of two argument typenames a friend of a template class. But i cannot manage to make it link.
Consider following example. Note, that the code is extremely simplified.
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct S;

template <typename U, typename T>
S<U> cast(S<T> const &); //PROBLEMATIC!

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, S<T> const & s); //no problem

template <typename T>
struct S
{
public:
    S() = default;
    ~S() = default;
    S( S const & ) = default;
    S( S&& ) = default;
    S(T val) : value{val} {}

    template <typename U>
    friend
    S<U> cast(S<T> const &); //PROBLEMATIC!

    friend
    std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& os, S<T> const & s); //no problem
private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, S<T> const & s) //no problem
{ return os << s.value; }

template <typename T, typename U>
S<U> cast(S<T> const & src) //problematic!
{return {static_cast<U>(src.value)};}

int main()
{
    S<int> s1{ 10 };
    auto s2{ cast<float>(s1) }; //linker error
    std::cout << s1 << ' ' << s2;
    return 0;
}

So, simply put, cast is a glorified conversion function. It cannot be rewritten as a regular conversion function in original design.
Notice, that template operator<< gets explicitly specialized, so there is no problem. However, cast can only be partially specialized, which is (AFAIK) not allowed for functions.
The question is: How (if) I can achieve this without explicitly instantiating S<float>?
I have tried removing forward declaration of cast before S. It did not help.
I have tried template <typename U> friend S<U> cast<U>(S<T> const &);. It raises partial specialization not allowed.
Exact linker errors:
<source>:26:10: error: function template partial specialization is not allowed
   26 |     S<U> cast<U>(S const &);
      |          ^   ~~~
1 error generated.

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/example-fd62b9.o: in function `main':
<source>:45:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `S<float> cast<float>(S<int> const&)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

live example

template <typename U> friend S<U> cast(S<T> const &); would declare a friend function with T fixed. Which might be valid but harder to define outside of the class, as you have to define it for each T. simpler would be to define it inside the class directly.

This is a working code
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct S;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, S<T> const& s);  // no problem

template <typename T>
struct S {
 public:
  S(T val) : value{val} {}

  template <typename U, typename V>
  friend S<U> cast(S<V> const&);

  friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& os, S<T> const& s);

 private:
  T value;
};

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, S<T> const& s) {
  return os << s.value;
}

template <typename U, typename T>
S<U> cast(S<T> const& src) {
  return {static_cast<U>(src.value)};
}

int main() {
  S<int> s1{10};
  auto s2{cast<float>(s1)};
  std::cout << s1 << ' ' << s2;
  return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/jTxrn96zz

The forward declaration of the friend cast is unnecessary.
For matching the friend declaration with the implementation, the friend must be declared with two template parameters.
  template <typename U, typename V>
  friend S<U> cast(S<V> const&);


The template parameters are swapped, you have tried this correctly but the friend declaration did not match the implementation.

